# HP Pavilion 15-P055 J1R84EA BeatsAudio

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the laptop in the title. It has BeatsAudio, but does not work in Ubuntu. It does work in Windows 8. I found this tutorial https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/ but I can not see any codec called "IDT". I can only see Realtec, so I can not see any of those pins metioned in the tutorial.

What could be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and try to launch alsamixer. Check if there is any option which contains the words "enhancement", "BeatsAudio" or "Equalizer". You can use M to enable/disable. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can not see anything like that, here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/Z6Jflmo.png

Comment: Try pressing right until you reach the end of the list? Perhaps there are more options but you did not see them all.

Comment: Forgot about that. But noting useful appeared I guess http://i.imgur.com/BJ4O7LB.png